# What is the newest version of hibernate-validator that gwt 2.7 support?

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, gwt

I've red in official documentation [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideValidation.html), which says to use `Hibernate validator 4.1.0.Final` which is 5 years old.

- I am not sure is old documentation or mistake?
- What version should I use?
- And If I should use proposed version, I would like to know why gwt dosen't support newer version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GWT **only** supports Hibernate Validator 4.1.0.Final, for **client-side** validation. Server side can use whichever version you want (a priori).

The reason GWT doesn't support a newer version is that nobody ever invested enough time to update. GWT has dependencies on HV internals so it's not as easy as switching versions.
In the future, the GWT team would like to move validation out into a separate project that could either be picked up by the community and maintained, or die.

For now, unless you think you could step in as a maintainer, I wouldn't recommend using javax.validation on the client side.

Comment: But `javax.validation` package contains only interfaces. As far I know there is no implementation? This is why I pick up at first `hibernate-validator`. About being a maintener- I've just started learning GWT- so not now. What validation do You use and why?